# Using Langchain with BigQuery - Error with tables containing RECORD fields

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-vertex-ai, langchain

I'm trying to build a simple Text to Query pipeline using Langchain, BigQuery and Vertex LLM.
Initiating the langchain SQLDatabase Object works fine

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import *
from langchain import SQLDatabase, SQLDatabaseChain

dataset_id = 'ecomm'
table_uri = f"bigquery://{PROJECT_ID}/{dataset_id}"
engine = create_engine(f"bigquery://{PROJECT_ID}/{dataset_id}")

db = SQLDatabase(engine=engine,metadata=MetaData(bind=engine),include_tables=['retail_products'],sample_rows_in_table_info=3)
```

but then, when calling a

```
print(db.table_info)
```

I get following error:

```
BadRequest: 400 Cannot access field key on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<text ARRAY<STRING>, numbers ARRAY<FLOAT64>, searchable BOOL, ...>>> at [1:406]
[SQL: SELECT `retail_products`.`name`, `retail_products`.`id`, `retail_products`.`type`, `retail_products`.`primaryProductId`, `retail_products`.`collectionMemberIds`, `retail_products`.`gtin`, `retail_products`.`categories`, `retail_products`.`title`, `retail_products`.`brands`, `retail_products`.`description`, `retail_products`.`languageCode`, `retail_products`.`attributes`, `retail_products`.`attributes`.`key`, `retail_products`.`attributes`.`value`, `retail_products`.`attributes`.`value`.`text`, `retail_products`.`attributes`.`value`.`numbers`, `retail_products`.`attributes`.`value`.`searchable`, `retail_products`.`attributes`.`value`.`indexable`, `retail_products`.`tags`, `retail_products`.`priceInfo`, `retail_products`.`priceInfo`.`currencyCode`, `retail_products`.`priceInfo`.`price`, `retail_products`.`priceInfo`.`originalPrice`, `retail_products`.`priceInfo`.`cost`, `retail_products`.`priceInfo`.`priceEffectiveTime`, `retail_products`.`priceInfo`.`priceExpireTime`, `retail_products`.`rating`, `retail_products`.`rating`.`ratingCount`, `retail_products`.`rating`.`averageRating`, `retail_products`.`rating`.`ratingHistogram`, `retail_products`.`expireTime`, `retail_products`.`ttl`, `retail_products`.`ttl`.`seconds`, `retail_products`.`ttl`.`nanos`, `retail_products`.`availableTime`, `retail_products`.`availability`, `retail_products`.`availableQuantity`, `retail_products`.`fulfillmentInfo`, `retail_products`.`fulfillmentInfo`.`type`, `retail_products`.`fulfillmentInfo`... FROM `retail_products` LIMIT %
```

The table schema is:

name  STRING  NULLABLE
id STRING  REQUIRED
type STRING  NULLABLE
primaryProductId STRING  NULLABLE
collectionMemberIds  STRING  REPEATED
gtin STRING  NULLABLE
categories STRING  REPEATED
title  STRING  REQUIRED
brands STRING  REPEATED
description  STRING  NULLABLE
languageCode STRING  NULLABLE
attributes RECORD  REPEATED
tags STRING  REPEATED
priceInfo  RECORD  NULLABLE
rating RECORD  NULLABLE
expireTime STRING  NULLABLE
ttl  RECORD  NULLABLE
availableTime  STRING  NULLABLE
availability STRING  NULLABLE
availableQuantity  INTEGER NULLABLE
fulfillmentInfo  RECORD  REPEATED
uri  STRING  NULLABLE
images RECORD  REPEATED
audience RECORD  NULLABLE
colorInfo  RECORD  NULLABLE
sizes  STRING  REPEATED
materials  STRING  REPEATED
patterns STRING  REPEATED
conditions STRING  REPEATED
retrievableFields  STRING  NULLABLE
publishTime  STRING  NULLABLE
promotions RECORD  REPEATED

Seems the problem is coming for RECORD type fields on my table.
This works fine on a simple table without nested fields

How can I fix this ?